# When using 'of' when is it really necessary to pluralize something or singularize it?

Tags: grammar

What would be right. Would you say a thousand points of battle damage are inflicted to you or would you say a thousand points of damage is inflicted to you?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it should be asked on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/). Note that things are inflicted ***on*** you, not ***to*** you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Plural/singular verb agreement with units](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/41155/plural-singular-verb-agreement-with-units)

Answer (score 1):

The thread titled [Plural/singular verb agreement with units](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/41155/plural-singular-verb-agreement-with-units) addresses this question, provided one accepts 'points' as being covered by 'units'.

Nobody would seriously argue for

> 'three miles are too far to walk'
>
> or
>
> '26 kg are too much/many for a healthy young lamb'.

Although there are grey areas, with 'less conventional' units such as points, frames, sets, goals, ends ..., the mass/continuous concept (a distance of 3 miles, a weight of around 26kg, a score of 1000 points) would result in singular agreement being used more often, at least in the UK.

> Six goals is a terrific score.
>
> 400 runs is a huge first-innings lead.
>
> 1000 points is quite a penalty.

There are, however, occasions when plural agreement **is** necessary:

> The three points on this fork are all bent.
>
> Both his goals were superbly taken.

Comment: Your "fork" example is one where *only* the plural is acceptable, but it might be worth flagging up a true "grey" area, such as *"I think three tines on a fork **are** quite enough"*. Some people might think that's the only correct version, and some might only accept *"I think three tines on a fork **is** quite enough"*, but I suspect most people would agree with me that both are fine.

Comment: Quite a dilemma. Or not.

Comment: It depends on what the verb *is* is referring to - the things that were counted (plural) or the number/count itself (singular). *"Three tines on a fork is a sufficient number"* *"The tines on a fork are meant to be slightly curved"* *"Six goals is a terrific score."* *"Six goals were scored."*

Comment: In general' it's more involved than looking for the possibility of an implied singular group noun. I'd say 'The team was founded in 1896' but 'The team were fighting amongst themselves'. The key question for logical concord is 'Are we **looking at the referent** as a composite whole or as individual components?' The jury was unrepresentative / the jury were arguing amongst themselves. Bacon and eggs is my favourite breakfast / Bacon and eggs are both overpriced in that shop.  And FF correctly identifies an ambiguous example: "I think three tines on a fork is/are quite enough".

Answer (score 0):

> a thousand points of battle damage *are* inflicted to you

Because 'a thousand points' is plural, the 'of battle damage' doesn't affect that.