# Subject Verb Agreement for of-phrase

Tags: verb-agreement

Four meters of cloth is/are required.

Which one is appropriate? I think it's `are` but I ain't sure...

I got confused because the discussion regarding the SV Agreement commonly talks about the fraction before `of-phrase` (like `"one-half of the cake"`).

Comment: I think this question has already found an answer :
http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/41155/plural-singular-verb-agreement-with-units; http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/22082/are-units-in-english-singular-or-plural ; english.stackexchange.com/questions/151819/your-1-hour-6-minutes-are-up-your-1-hour-6-minutes-is-up

Comment: The problem is that cloth may be regarded as countable or not.

Answer (score 2):

The previous answers on this topic are of limited help in that they are somewhat-confused and often contradictory.  Look to the meaning of your sentence.  If you consider your subject a collective thing that you think of as a unit, then use a singular verb.  If you consider your subject a multiple with separate identifies, then use a plural verb:

> Twenty miles **is** the distance to the nearest city.

The twenty act together as a measure, so the verb is **singluar**.

> The last twenty miles **were** increasingly difficult to travel.

Each mile was more difficult than the last and thus distinguishable from the previous, so the verb is **plural**.

> Three milliliters **is** the dose the doctor prescribed.

Three milliliters is one amount that makes up a single dose, so the verb is **singular**.

The doctor prescribed for him one-milliliter doses of medication to be taken three times a day.  The first three milliliters **were** enough to cure him.

The three milliliters came separately, one at a time, so the verb is **plural**.