# 5 bottles of milk + IS or ARE?

Tags: verb-agreement

Q 1. Is the subject "5 bottles of milk" countable or uncountable?

Q 2. What kind of verb should I use for "5 bottles of milk", singular or
    plural?

Many thanks!

Comment: Well, five bottles of milk *is* a lot to drink at once, but five bottles of milk *are* in the fridge. Is the *concept* you’re trying to get across mass or countable?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Plural/singular verb agreement with units](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/41155/plural-singular-verb-agreement-with-units). I must admit, however, that the question of whether a "bottle' is a unit [of measure], in the same sense that, say, a "quart" is gives this question a slightly different wrinkle.

Comment: @DanBron So you mean if the concept is regarded as one, it will be singular, but if I talk about it separately as 5 individual bottles, it will be plural, right?

Comment: @KateNg Yep! You got it.

Comment: Thank you @DanBron

Answer (score 1):

Grammatically, '5 bottles...' is a plural noun, and should be followed by 'are'.  But, considered a phrase, 'five bottles of milk' is singular, just like I started my comment here, '5 bottles of milk' is a plural noun.

Other similarly confusing usages are, say, a lot of examples....are/is.  According to grammar rules, it should be 'is', but it is for sure plural.  Still confusing is another example, 'A number of opportunities'....is/ are...

May be, others have better answers