# that does not/do not, was/were

Tags: grammatical-number, ambiguity, verb-agreement, measuring-units, compound-predicates

I have the two sentences below and I can't seem to figure out which one, in both cases, would be correct. They "sound" equally correct to me.

#### Sentence 1

- We should make patterns that are beautiful and that **does not** allow for replication to take place.
- We should make patterns that are beautiful and that **do not** allow for replication to take place.

#### Sentence 2

- In the lab, 10 ml of liquid **was** diluted with 1500 ml.
- In the lab, 10 ml of liquid **were** diluted with 1500 ml.

I was hoping someone could explain which is correct and why.

Comment: Does this answer your second question? [Plural/singular verb agreement with units](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/41155/plural-singular-verb-agreement-with-units) Your first question is basic agreement of subject and verb form (patterns ... that do not allow ...).

Comment: What's the subject of *do/does not allow* in your first sentence? Is it *patterns*, or have you introduced a new subject when you talk about *that*? Do you have two complete independent clauses as though it were *1. We should make patterns that are beautiful. 2. Doing this does not allow for replication to make place*? Repeating the *that* like this introduces irresolvable syntactic ambiguity.