# Why is it "two column" and not "two columns"?

Tags: grammar

Recently, during conversation, a colleague and I were debating why it's common to see "one column, two column", and not "one column, two column**s**".

There are several other words like this, where their singular is used instead of their plural.

Examples of its usage:

1. That building is held up by 2 columns
2. That building has a 2 column layout        <------- Why is this not column**s**?

Why is it so?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. You should find the answer in *[Are units in English singular or plural?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/22082/are-units-in-english-singular-or-plural)*

Comment: The explanation aside (which is in the other question), there should be a hyphen in your second usage: *a 2-column layout*.