# Is it 0.5 ampere or 0.5 amperes?

Tags: grammatical-number, measuring-units

If it's written as "0.5 ampere", shouldn't we write "0.5 hour" and not "0.5 hours"?

Comment: It's half an amp.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are units in English singular or plural?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/22082/are-units-in-english-singular-or-plural)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be "0.5 amperes" and "0.5 hours". It is a rule in English that for any value other than 1, the units should be written in the plural form if they are being spelled out. If you are using abbreviations for units, however, they should remain singular in spelling (e.g. "0.5 A" not "0.5 As").

Comment: Any value except 1 or -1, but otherwise I agree with you.

Comment: Imagining a current of -0.5 A is hard.

Comment: Please add supporting references, linked and attributed, to answers. But note that many questions are duplicates; this has certainly been answered before, and ELU aims to avoid bloat.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - I was referring to the general rule, but in the context of electricity volts can certainly have negative values and that may be directly relevant for somebody who asked about amperes.

Comment: Voltage is measured relative to some reference point. You can't have less than zero current.